# A constant value is expected (switch TimeOnly in C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, switch-statement, .net-6.0

I am totally new in C#, learning from scratch.
Now with practicing switch statement I want to compare TimeOnly variable for meeting time in day.
But VS returns me "A Constant value is expected".

```
using System.Globalization;

TimeOnly testTimeOnly = TimeOnly.ParseExact("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeOnly testMorning = TimeOnly.ParseExact("06:00:00", "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


switch (testTimeOnly)
{

    case >= TimeOnly.Parse("00:00:00") and < testMorning:
        Console.WriteLine("Its night right now.");
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown part of the day!");
        break;
}
```

I tried some parsing, using hardcoded value or variable, but result is the same.
Even declaring variable as constant does not help.

In some other thread I found, that it can occur because value must be compiled, but do not know, how to write values other way.

I want to compare testTimeOnly to some time inverval and get some message.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: What you want should be done with an if-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried some parsing, using hardcoded value or variable, but result is
> the same. Even declaring variable as constant does not help

Actually, if you check [DateTime Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-8.0) you would seen [Hour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.hour?view=net-8.0)  property within it which should look like as following:

[image]

Therefore, when you would pass or evaluate any time comparison you ought to extract the hour from given format for your scenario which is HH:mm:ss. Once you would extract the hour now you could execute your comparison using  [switch  statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements).

Let's check in action what you are trying to achieve.

```cs
            TimeOnly testTimeOnly = TimeOnly.ParseExact("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            TimeOnly testMorning = TimeOnly.ParseExact("06:00:00", "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var checkNight = testTimeOnly.Hour;
            var checkMorning = testMorning.Hour;
            switch (checkNight)
            {
                case int time when (time >= 6 && time <= 12):
                    Console.WriteLine($"Hello , good morning");
                    break;
                case int time when (time >= 12 && time <= 17):
                    Console.WriteLine($"Hello , good afternoon");
                    break;
                case int time when (time >= 0):
                    Console.WriteLine($"Hello ,{testTimeOnly} Its night right now");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine($"Unknown part of the day!");
                    break;
                   
            }
```

**Note:**  As you can see I am extracting hour from testTimeOnly which will return 0 means over 23.

Output:

[image]

**Daynamic Comparison:**

However, if you would like to extract and compare dynamic time reagrdless of time zone the elegant way would be as following:

```
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime utcTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
            TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("China Standard Time");

            DateTime yourLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, cstZone);
            var hour = yourLocalTime.Hour;

            switch (hour)
            {
                case int time when (time >= 0 && time <= 5):
                    Console.WriteLine($"Hello ,Its mid night now");
                    break;
                case int time when (time >= 6 && time <= 12):
                    Console.WriteLine($"Hello , Its morning now");
                    break;
                case int time when (time >= 12 && time <= 17):
                    Console.WriteLine($"Hello , Its after noon");
                    break;
                case int time when (time >= 17 && time <= 19):
                    Console.WriteLine($"Hello , Its evening");
                    break;
                case int time when (time >= 19 && time <= 23):
                    Console.WriteLine($"Hello , Its Night");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine($"Hello and welcome!");
                    break;
            }
```

In addition to this, you can [get your required time zone here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones?view=windows-11#time-zones)

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on time conversion you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow?view=net-8.0)